# How do I install multiple OSes on a USB flash drive?

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, operating-systems, linux-distributions

I would like to try out different Linux distros on the go using a USB flash drive.

Is it possible to install multiple Linux OSes on a single USB drive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several options available

## **Option 1: MultiBootUSB**

You could try *MultiBootUSB* downloadable [here](http://multibootusb.sourceforge.net/)

> MultiBootUSB is available on SourceForge and appears to be a pretty popular program for just this kind of task. The MultiBootUSB software is also a portable application, meaning you simply put the MultiBootUSB-6.4.1.exe file onto your USB drive and run it all from the USB drive.

## **Option 2: XBoot**

You could try *XBoot*, it has considerably more documentation that MultiUSBBoot, although not really needed it's nice to know it's there, it's downloadable [Here](https://sites.google.com/site/shamurxboot/download)

> The speed with which XBoot added the ISO files was also blindingly fast – mere seconds per ISO – versus the hour it took me to load the same ISOs into MultiBootUSB.

## **Option 3: YUMI**

Downloadable [here](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) - I don't have much experience with this tool, so I'm not going to say anything about it.

For your consideration, there is a great MakeUseOf article on this topic, located [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-install-multiple-bootable-operating-systems-on-one-usb-stick/)

Answer (score 1):

There's a tool that can do just that: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/

Comment: Does this tool do _multiple_ OS installations? I'm having a hard time finding it on the site.

Comment: Nice I'll definitely check out pendrive linux.